# Fastest way to read a column of numbers into an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Say if I have a column of numbers (how many of them could vary, but could be anywhere between 1000-10000) and I would like to read all of them into an array in VBA, what is the fastest way of doing so?

Obviously I can create an array of size 10000 and do a for/while-loop but is there any way that's faster than this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Like this?

```
Dim Ar as Variant

Ar = Sheets("Sheet").Range("A1:A10000").Value
```

If you do not know the last row then you can find the last row using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) and then use the above code as

```
Ar = Sheets("Sheet").Range("A1:A" & LRow).Value
```

Comment: If you're looking for the fastest approach I think you can use `.Value2`. The only difference I have noticed is with dates where `.Value2` returns the serial number instead of the [locally] formatted date.

Comment: Value does not return a formatted date, it returns a Variant(datetime) type. If you are seeing it as a formatted date, that is just because the viewer is showing you the default ToString(). It is not a string.

Comment: Worth mentioning (I didn't see it mentioned elsewhere): this answer returns multidimensional array even though there is only one column involved. The Ar array can be used like Ar(1,1) etc. not like this Ar(1). Also, even if you have Option Base 0 in your module, it will be a Base 1 array.

Comment: Thank you moutainclimber, that was the piece I was missing.